# Mysql c++ connector using all system memory

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

This code looks like using all the system memory. Why does it happend?

```
sql::Statement *Query;
sql::ResulSet *Result;
while(1){
   Query = con->createStatement();
   Result = Query->executeQuery("SELECT `Some` FROM `Table` LIMIT 1");
   Result->next();
   Result->close(); 
   Query->close();
   cout << "console message..." << endl;
   //delete Query; SEGFAULT
}
```

If i comment all the lines except the cout the memory doesn't get filled. But using the SQL looks like Query = con->createStatement; is not replacing the old Query value and Result = bla; is not replacing the old value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like there is no info on google. I found what was the problem.

as SJuan76 said each call to createStatement and to executeQuery is a new object

So i started to do a lot of tryes and i figure out of the following

1. Use createStatement just once
2. Before deleting Result check if it's open and close
3. Delete Respuesta
4. Only delete con and Query at the end of the program auto_ptr(is your friend sometimes)

So the code to get the "forever running" program to use always the same memory shoud look like this

```
sql::Statement *Query;
sql::ResulSet *Result;
Query = con->createStatement();
while(1){
 if(!Result->isClosed()) Result->close();
 delete Result;
 Result = Query->executeQuery("SELECT `Some` FROM `Table` LIMIT 1");
 Result->next();
 cout << "console message..." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`createStatement()` and `executeQuery` are creating new objects (which are the ones you store in `Query` and `Result`. Unless you explicitly delete them, they will remain in memory.

Add

```
  delete Result;
  delete Query;
```

To your loop.

BTW, this is in the connector documentation (together with sample code).

Comment: adding delete Query at the end of the loop(just after the cout) makes segfault

Comment: This is the reference I used, I do not know what may be troubling you. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

Comment: yeah i have a delete if for any reason the loop must break.

Comment: yeah i have a delete if for any reason the loop must break.

But it's a persistent program, it must be running "forever" and looks like there is not a wipe() method or a clean method to clear the unused reserved memory by sql::Statement and sql::ResulSelt (both are problematic), close(); for any reason slows down the memory, but after a few 10000 loops, it will use 4x memory, and in less than 1 hour it will be using  1gB memory. I can't find documentation, the only idea is to use a vector of Statement and other of ResultSet and delete the "before entry"... dirty fix. Thanks for your time